# Xpath: Extracting text of tags between two different types of tags using selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm using Selenium and I'm having a problem selecting tags between two other types of tags.

```
<div class='my-class'>
<p>This is a paragraph 1</p><p>This is a paragraph 2</p><p>This is a paragraph 3</p>
<h3>Introduction</h3>
<p>This is a paragraph 4</p><p>This is a paragraph 5</p><p>This is a paragraph 6</p>
<p>This is a paragraph 7</p><p>This is a paragraph 8</p><p>This is a paragraph 9</p>
<h3>Conclusion</h3>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is to grab only the paragraphs between the "Introduction" and "Conclusion" tags, nothing else before or after.  This is the xpath notation that seems to work perfectly with an online validator but not in Selenium:

```
//div[@class='my-class']/h3[contains(., 'Conclusion')]/preceding-sibling::p[preceding-sibling::h3[contains(., 'Introduction')]]
```

Here is my Selenium code:

```
allElementsArray = driver.findElements(By.xpath(path));
```

I believe the xpath notation works because it works with a validator, but when running with Selenium it returns no matches.  What am I doing wrong?

Tried the xpath in an xpath web tester and it worked, but it does not work in Selenium code.

Answer (score 0):

The XPath looks OK to me. Maybe there's a bug in the XPath implementation. That would depend on which driver you are using, I think.

It seems to me, though, that if it did work correctly it would return the `p` elements in reverse order (because it returns elements read from the `preceding-sibling` axis), and I'm thinking it's unlikely you'd actually want that.

To work around the bug, you might try this slightly simpler XPath query:

```xml
//div[@class='my-class']/p
   [following-sibling::h3[contains(., 'Conclusion')]]
   [preceding-sibling::h3[contains(., 'Introduction')]]
```

Or if you know the full text of the `h3` elements, then you don't need `contains`:

```xml
//div[@class='my-class']/p
   [following-sibling::h3='Conclusion')]
   [preceding-sibling::h3='Introduction')]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following XPath works with a XPath 1.0 capable tool like `xmllint`
`//div[@class="my-class"]/p[following-sibling::h3[contains(., "Conclusion")] and preceding-sibling::h3[contains(., "Introduction")]]`

```
xmllint --html --xpath '//div[@class="my-class"]/p[following-sibling::h3[contains(., "Conclusion")] and preceding-sibling::h3[contains(., "Introduction")]]' tmp.html
```

Result

```
<p>This is a paragraph 4</p>
<p>This is a paragraph 5</p>
<p>This is a paragraph 6</p>
<p>This is a paragraph 7</p>
<p>This is a paragraph 8</p>
<p>This is a paragraph 9</p>
```